# Rails joining table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have asked a recent similar question but come across more issues.

I have a Guest and Booking model where each Guest has many Bookings.

For a guest to access their booking they need to enter the id of the booking which is held in the Bookings table and their email address which is in the Guest table.

I currently have a join:

```
guest_has_booking = Guest.joins(:bookings).where('bookings.id' => id)
```

but I don't know how to check to see if there is a guest with the booking id.

In my controller I have a conditional:

```
if guest_has_booking

end
```

but it seems to be TRUE when it shouldn't be. For example I can just enter a booking ID that does exist and it will mean guest_has_booking is TRUE.

I also need to be able to handle things gracefully when no records are found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably returning a blank array, which evaluates to true as a boolean.  Use the `blank?` method to see if you have results.

Try something like

```
guest_has_booking = !Guest.joins(:bookings).where('bookings.id' => id).blank?
```

(note the negation `!` at the beginning)